# Using external json to a jade in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, xmlhttprequest

How can I pass a Json Object from XMLHttpRequest to my jade file? There is only a blank page displayed and the server is sending a 500 internal error for the get method.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var XMLHttpRequest = require("XMLHttpRequest").XMLHttpRequest;

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    getJSON('/pros/' + id, function (data) {
        res.render('consultProfessionnal', { prof:JSON.stringify(data)});
    }, function (status) {
        alert('Something went wrong.');
    });
});

module.exports = router;

var getJSON = function (url, successHandler, errorHandler) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        var status = xhr.status;
        if (request.readyState === 4 && status === 200) {
            successHandler && successHandler(xhr.response);
        } else {
            errorHandler && errorHandler(status);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
};
```

Here is my jade file where I send the json object:

```
extends layout
block content

    .container()
        #viewItem
            if prof.sexe==1
                a
                  img.img-responsive(src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/user_male2-128.png', alt='', style='padding-left:60px;')
            else if prof.sexe==0
                a
                  img.img-responsive(src='https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/futurama/128/Brainslug.png', alt='', style='padding-left:60px;')
            else
                a
                  img.img-responsive(src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/user_female2-128.png', alt='', style='padding-left:60px;')

            h2= prof.prenom + ' ' + prof.nom
            h4.space= 'Speciality : ' + prof.specialite

            if prof.sexe==1
              h4= 'Sexe : Male'
            else if prof.sexe==0
              h4= 'Sexe : Other'
            else
              h4= 'Sexe : Female'
            h4= 'Total visit : ' + prof.nbreTotal
            h4= 'Total patient : ' + prof.nbrePatient

            hr
            h3 2014 Patient(s)
            hr
            each visite in prof.patient2014        
                li= visite.prenom + ' ' + visite.nom

            button(
              type='submit'
              style='width: 25px; height: 25px; background-color: black;'
              id=prof._id
              onclick="alerted()"
            )

    script(src='/stylesheets/js/jquery.js')
    script(src="../javascripts/script.js")
    script(src='/stylesheets/js/bootstrap.min.js')
```

Comment: Will you post your jade file as well?

Comment: You're mixing client and server code in awkward ways. Where is this code running?

Comment: I just added the jade, and its running from an express application where I have to call my REST service to print my data in a jade website

Comment: My service works fine since when I print them in the console it works. My problem is retrieving them to pass it in a different route...

Comment: My best guess is that `getJSON('/pros/' + id,` works fine when you test it in the browser, but fails on the server.  The server doesn't know how to handle relative requests. So it would need a `getJSON('http://mydomain.tld/pros/' + id,`.

Comment: Ok so that a breakthrough, the jade is now displaying, but the server still send a 500 internal error for the request on the button:  onclick="href='http://localhost:3000/professionnal/' + id"

Comment: And the object sent is 'undefined'...

Comment: Ok i got it fixed from the help you gave me with getJSON('http://mydomain.tld/pros/' + id.If you want to answer so i could promote ur comment and close the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here: `getJSON('/pros/' + id,`

In the browser a relative url will resolve to {protocol}://{domain).{tld}{port?}{relative url}
With the protocol, domain, tld and port being based on the page.

However on the server there is no page so you need to manually resolve the url.

So to solve it you can change it to `getJSON('http://' + req.headers.host + '/pros/' + id,` and it should work. (or any other way you want to resolve the host)